# OpenMDAOv1.x: warning: parallel derivs not running under MPI

Tags: parallel-processing, mpi, openmdao

I just finished installing OpenMDAOv1.3 on our super computer. The installation was successful and all tests either passed or skipped. However, when I ran the tests I got the following warning:

```
*path/OpenMDAO/openmdao/core/driver.py:228: UserWarning: parallel derivs %s specified but not running under MPI
  warnings.warn("parallel derivs %s specified but not running under MPI")
```

I'm not sure what to do about this (if anything) and so I am looking for information about the implications of the warning message. We are planning on running in parallel with the built in MPI functionality of OpenMDAO. I currently have openmpi-1.8.4 loaded on the system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can ignore that warning... it's just because the test is not running under MPI. (The test will be fixed to suppress the warning).

There are additional steps you need to take to run in parallel.  This has not yet been documented, but some of us have been using the following steps when working in an anaconda environment:

```
sudo apt-get install openmpi-bin openmpi-doc libopenmpi-dev
pip install mpi4py # do not use conda install, this causes an mpich conflict
sudo apt-get install liblapack-dev gfortran
pip install --no-deps git+https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc@v3.5 
conda install cython
pip install --no-deps  git+https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc4py@3.5
```

To verify you are good to go, you can run the tests in the mpitests directory as follows:

```
cd mpitests
find . -name "*.py" -exec python {} \;
```

Alternatively you can use the testflo package from

```
pip install git+https://github.com/naylor-b/testflo.git
```

and from the OpenMDAO directory, issue the following command:

```
testflo .  -i
```

Note that this assumes a Linux type operating system.. Parallel execution on Windows is not currently supported

Answer (score 1):

To get OpenMDAO succesfully running in parallel using Conda, OpenMPI, mpi4py, PETSc and petsc4py I have adapted [this](https://gist.github.com/robfalck/92a587b49d73cb24e53a) procedure for OS X to Ubuntu:

### Prerequisites

**Ubuntu**

```
sudo apt-get install libibnetdisc-dev
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev libatlas-dev liblapack-dev
```

### Install OpenMPI

Download OpenMPI: https://www.open-mpi.org/software/ompi/v1.10/

### Extract and configure

```
cd ~/Downloads/openmpi-1.10.1
mkdir build
cd build
# I prefer to keep /usr/local clean, so I put it in /opt/openmpi
./configure --prefix=/opt/openmpi --with-devel-headers --enable-binaries
make
sudo make install
```

### Add the following to your bash profile

**OS X**

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=${DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH}:/opt/openmpi/lib
export PATH=${PATH}:/opt/openmpi/bin
```

**Ubuntu**

```
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/openmpi/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export PATH=/opt/openmpi/bin:$PATH
```

### Activate your conda environment

```
source activate myenv
```

### Install mpi4py

```
git clone https://github.com/mpi4py/mpi4py.git ./mpi4py.git
cd mpi4py.git
python setup.py build --mpicc=/opt/openmpi/bin/mpicc
python setup.py install
```

### Install PETSc

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc.git ./petsc.git
cd petsc.git
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

### Install petsc4py

```
git clone https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc4py.git ./petsc4py.git
cd petsc4py.git
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

Comment: If you're working on a cluster, you probably don't want to compile openMPI yourself. You also might want to manually compile petsc rather than doing it through pip if you decide to use a debug or complex build of it.