# How do I fix version error when installing petsc4py for use in openmdao

Tags: python, openmdao, petsc

I am trying to install petsc4py with direction found on the Python [website](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/petsc4py) but I am getting an error. How do I fix this cant find correct version error? My overall goal is to be able to use openMDAO but I need to start with getting petsc4py working.

The following is the input of the command and then the error I am receiving

```
pip install petsc petsc4py
Collecting petsc
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement petsc (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for petsc
```

Comment: See also [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33766356/openmdaov1-x-warning-parallel-derivs-not-running-under-mpi/33777360#33777360) to install petsc.

Answer (score 3):

Which platform are you running on (Windows, Linux, OS X)?

I have had good luck with installing using pip directly on the BitBucket repos:

```
pip install --no-deps git+https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc@v3.5
pip install --no-deps git+https://bitbucket.org/petsc/petsc4py@3.5
```